# Button for each group in a grid

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to have a button for each group in my grid. Below is a screenshot which shows where I would like the buttons to be. Basically I just need a button per group.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36721131/screenshot.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe modifying the Group Header can be useful for you. Read
[Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.groupHeaderTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-groupHeaderTpl)